# Tire / Elasticsearch for HABTM associated models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, elasticsearch, tire

I am trying to implement a full-text searching with tire/elasticsearch for my Client model. I have a set of users, working with clients. There is a HABTM association between Client and User models.

There is a `manager` function to scope only clients, managed by a particular user (in most cases it is the user currently logged in). I would like to implement a search filter in tire that would work much the same way as it works with ActiveRecord. It does not work with tire (throwing the `no filter registered for [user_ids]` error).

```
s.filter :user_ids, manager(params[:manager]).map(&:id) 
  if params[:manager].present?
```

I believe I might be doing something completely off the wall here, but what is wrong with the way I do that and what tutorial/reading would you recommend?

Here is the model.

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_and_belongs_to_many :users, :uniq => true

  ## Tire would-be implementation
  # include Tire::Model::Search
  # include Tire::Model::Callbacks
  # mapping do
  #   indexes :name
  #   indexes :comment
  #   indexes :user_ids
  # end

  def self.manager(user_id)
    joins(:users).merge(User.current(user_id))
  end

  def self.index_search(params={})
    ## Tire would-be-implementation - does not work
    # tire.search(load: true) do |s|
    #   s.query { string params[:search], default_operator: "AND" } if params[:search].present?
    #   s.filter :user_ids, manager(params[:manager]).map(&:id) if params[:manager].present?
    # end

    # ActiveRecord implementation - works
    if params[:manager].present?
      if params[:search].present?
        @clients = manager(params[:manager]).where(['name LIKE ?', "%#{params[:search]}%"])
      else 
        @clients = manager(params[:manager])
      end
    else
      if params[:search].present?
        @clients = where(['name LIKE ?', "%#{params[:search]}%"])
      else 
        @clients = all
      end
    end
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
t.filter :not , {:ids => { :values => self.manager(params[:manager]).map(&:id) }} if params[:manager].present?
```

or

```
t.filter :ids, :values => self.manager(params[:manager]).map(&:id) if params[:manager].present?
```